# Create aws_subnet using for_each loop in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I create resource "aws_subnet" using count expression. I'd like to use for_each instead of count, but need help with the correct syntax.

```
variable "privateSubnetCIDR" {
      type = list(string)
      default = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24"]
    }
data "aws_availability_zones" "availableAZ" {}
    
resource "aws_subnet" "privatesubnet" {
  count                   = length(var.privateSubnetCIDR)
  cidr_block              = tolist(var.privateSubnetCIDR)[count.index]
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.dev_vpc.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names[count.index]
  tags = {
    name        = "${var.environment}-privatesubnet-${count.index + 1}"
    AZ          = data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names[count.index]
    Environment = "${var.environment}-privatesubnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, it works. I just want to understand how to use for_each in this case.

Comment: You are already using for each in `for_each = toset(var.publicSubnetCIDR)`? So if it works, what's the problem?

Comment: My fault, posted incorrect code. Here is the working example with count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to use `for_each` would be as follows:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "privatesubnet" {
  for_each                = toset(var.privateSubnetCIDR)
  cidr_block              = each.key
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.dev_vpc.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names, index(var.privateSubnetCIDR, each.key))
  tags = {
    name        = "environment-privatesubnet-${index(var.privateSubnetCIDR, each.key) + 1}"
    AZ          = element(data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names, index(var.privateSubnetCIDR, each.key))
    Environment = "environment-privatesubnet"
  }
}
```

The simpler way would be:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "privatesubnet" {
  for_each                = {for idx, val in var.privateSubnetCIDR: idx => val}
  cidr_block              = each.value
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.dev_vpc.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names, each.key)
  tags = {
    name        = "environment-privatesubnet-${each.key + 1}"
    AZ          = element(data.aws_availability_zones.availableAZ.names, each.key)
    Environment = "environment-privatesubnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have troubles when trying to get subnet_id in the next block:
`resource "aws_route_table_association" "nat_routeTableAssociation" {
    count = length(var.privateSubnetCIDR)
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat_routetable[count.index].id
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.privatesubnet[count.index].id`
I can't use for_each here, because route_table uses count. Is there any way to get subnet_id without for_each in this block?

Comment: @bohdan If you have new issues, new SO question should be made. My answer correctly addresses your current question.